# SendGrid - Unsubscribe Code - Not clickable

Tags: sendgrid

Last week our SendGrid unsubscribe button (we have one in the text) was working fine.  Format was {{{unsubscribe}}}. Not sure why not working now.
Sometimes unclickable.  Sometimes gives an error "   Your file couldn’t be accessedIt may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
"
We do have an unsubscribe group.

Maybe a glitch at Sendgrid.  Code is below.  Any thoughts would be very much appreciated!

Code we have is:

```
                         <tr>
                        <td width="400" valign="middle" align="center" style="padding:10px"><a href="{{{unsubscribe}}}" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:15px;line-height: 18px; font-weight:500;text-decoration:none;;font-family:arial,sans-serif;">No, sorry, {{insert SchoolName 'default=our school'}} won't be participating.<br /> Please unsubscribe me.</a></td>
                      </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer.  The link with {{{unsubscribe}}} only seems to work when you use a SingleSend and, in response to the preliminary prompts before you can "send" **you need to select which Unsubscribe Group you have created**.  For some reason, I did not see those prompts before.